# (R) Download a file with direct download link that works in browser, but won't in R

Tags: php, html, r, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to download a lot of files from the WorldPop UK site for a lot of countries I have in a dataset (not just the small example). Downloading each file would be very time consuming and tedious.

I'm fairly familiar with download methods in R, but I can't get these downloads to work. I know it is because the download links run through html somehow, but I'm no good with html or java.

I have done a lot of reading on httr, RCurl, and RSelenium. I'd prefer a solution avoiding RSelenium as I'm far more familiar with the other packages and may share the code and don't want to have to set up a browser every time (at least that is my understanding)

Can somebody help me out with this?

Direct download link to a small text (.txt) file that works fine in browser, but not in R using download.file or curl_download:
http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php?dataset=140&action=download&file=60

Site with index of files for Nigeria for example (you can see the href= links in the html code): http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php?dataset=140&action=dir

On chrome, view-source:http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php?dataset=140&action=dir

The download links are between lines 558 and 559 on my developer console.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. Are you not able to get `download` working from `r` for say a sample file?

Comment: That URL (ending in 60) results in a _"Please navigate back to the data page via this link"_ message. (update: they all do)

Comment: Yeah my bad on the links. My browser obviously still had the cookies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, they *certainly* do not make this easy. On top of a convoluted "web app" they also tried to do the right thing and use sha1 has validation on sourced javascript resources, but failed to keep those maintained (i.e. secure browsers won't be able to work with that site).

*Anyway*, here's what you have to do to avoid `splashr` or `RSelenium`/`seleniumPipes`. I used your "README" example and there are plenty of comments.

My advice is to wrap one or more bits into a function for easier use and also consider wrapping various calls in `purrr` helpers like `safely` (there are also "retry" examples oot and aboot).

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# Need to "prime" the session with a cookie
res <- GET(url="http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/data_sources/")

# Get the page contents
pg <- content(res)

# Find the summary links
summary_link_nodes <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href,'summary')]")

# extract the table cells & href so we can make a data frame
map(summary_link_nodes, html_nodes, xpath=".//../..") %>%
  map(html_children) %>%
  map(html_text) %>%
  map(~.[1:4]) %>%
  map(as.list) %>%
  map_df(set_names, c("continent", "country", "resolution", "data_type")) %>%
  bind_cols(
    data_frame(
      summary_link = sprintf("http://www.worldpop.org.uk%s", html_attr(summary_link_nodes, "href"))
    )
  ) -> world_pop_data

glimpse(world_pop_data)
## Observations: 462
## Variables: 5
## $ continent    <chr> "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Afri...
## $ country      <chr> "Algeria", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burund...
## $ resolution   <chr> "100m", "100m", "100m", "100m", "100m", "100m", "100m", "100m", "...
## $ data_type    <chr> "Population", "Population", "Population", "Population", "Populati...
## $ summary_link <chr> "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP0000...

# just see "Nigeria" data
filter(world_pop_data, country=="Nigeria")
## # A tibble: 8 x 5
##   continent country resolution         data_type                                                      summary_link
##       <chr>   <chr>      <chr>             <chr>                                                             <chr>
## 1    Africa Nigeria       100m        Population http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00196
## 2    Africa Nigeria        1km            Births http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00357
## 3    Africa Nigeria        1km       Pregnancies http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00465
## 4    Africa Nigeria        1km Contraceptive Use http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00198
## 5    Africa Nigeria        1km          Literacy http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00199
## 6    Africa Nigeria        1km           Poverty http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00200
## 7    Africa Nigeria        1km          Stunting http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00201
## 8    Africa Nigeria       100m    Age structures http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00194
```

I'm *fairly* certain you can start any file download session attempt from one of ^^ URLs, but you need to test that as you may need to always start from the "main" page (as noted, it maintains session position based on cookies).

```
# get nigeria population URL
filter(world_pop_data, country=="Nigeria") %>%
  filter(data_type=="Population") %>%
  pull(summary_link) -> nigeria_pop

nigeria_pop
# [1] "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary?doi=10.5258/SOTON/WP00196"

# follow it
GET(url=nigeria_pop) -> res2
pg2 <- content(res2)
```

That page always has a `<form>` on it so we need to "submit" said form with a `POST`:

```
# extract "form" fields (that page does a POST request)
fields <- html_nodes(pg2, "form#conform > input")
fields <- set_names(xml_attr(fields, "value"), html_attr(fields, "name"))

str(as.list((fields))) # just to show what it looks like
## List of 4
##  $ zip_id   : chr "140"
##  $ zip_title: chr "Nigeria 100m Population"
##  $ decoy    : chr "website"
##  $ website  : chr NA

# submit the form with the field data.
# NOTE we need to add the `Referer` (the faux page we're on)
POST(
  url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/download/",
  add_headers(`Referer` = nigeria_pop),
  body = list(
    client_first_name = "",
    client_last_name = "",
    client_organization = "",
    client_country = "",
    client_email = "",
    client_message = "",
    zip_id = fields["zip_id"],
    zip_title = fields["zip_title"],
    decoy = fields["decoy"],
    website = "",
    download = "Browse Individual Files"
  ),
  encode = "form"
) -> res3
```

Somewhere on the resultant page is the "Switch to file list" link, so we need to find it and follow it:

```
# find the link that has the file list
pg3 <- content(res3)
html_nodes(pg3, xpath=".//a[contains(., 'switch to')]") %>%
  html_attr("href") -> file_list_query_string # just to see the format
## [1] "?dataset=140&action=dir"

# follow that link (we need to use some of the previous captured fields)
GET(
  url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php",
  query = list(
    dataset = fields["zip_id"],
    action = "dir"
  )
) -> res4
```

Now, we build a data frame of all the links on that page:

```
pg4 <- content(res4)

data_frame(
  group_name = html_nodes(pg4, "a.dl") %>% html_text(),
  href = html_nodes(pg4, "a.dl") %>% html_attr("href")
) -> downloads

downloads
## # A tibble: 60 x 2
##                      group_name                                 href
##                           <chr>                                <chr>
##  1                  Licence.txt  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=1
##  2            NGA_metadata.html  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=2
##  3         NGA_pph_v2c_2006.tfw  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=3
##  4         NGA_pph_v2c_2006.tif  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=4
##  5 NGA_pph_v2c_2006.tif.aux.xml  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=5
##  6     NGA_pph_v2c_2006.tif.xml  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=6
##  7         NGA_pph_v2c_2010.tfw  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=7
##  8         NGA_pph_v2c_2010.tif  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=8
##  9 NGA_pph_v2c_2010.tif.aux.xml  ?dataset=140&action=download&file=9
## 10     NGA_pph_v2c_2010.tif.xml ?dataset=140&action=download&file=10
## # ... with 50 more rows
```

While I noted earlier you may need to begin always from the start or from that previous link page, you may also be able to download all these sequentially as well. You need to do the testing tho. This is a painful site to deal with.

```
filter(downloads, str_detect(group_name, "README")) %>%
  pull(href) -> readme_query_string # we need this below
readme_query_string
## [1] "?dataset=140&action=download&file=60"

# THERE IS A RLY GD CHANCE YOU'LL NEED TO USE timeout() for
# some of these calls. That server takes a while
# right here is where that modal "preparing the data" is shown.
# I'm 99% certain this is there to slow down crawlers/scrapers.
GET(
  url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php",
  query = parse_url(readme_query_string)$query,
  verbose()
) -> res5
```

This is not what you'll really do. You'll likely want to `content(res5, as="raw")` and `writeBin()` it since some (most) aren't plain text. But, this is to show that the above all works:

```
content(res5, as="text") %>%
  cat()
## WorldPop Africa dataset details
## _______________________
##
## DATASET: Alpha version 2010, 2015 and 2020 estimates of numbers of people per pixel ('ppp') and people per hectare ('pph'), with national totals adjusted to match UN population division estimates (http://esa.un.org/wpp/) and remaining unadjusted.
## REGION: Africa
## SPATIAL RESOLUTION: 0.000833333 decimal degrees (approx 100m at the equator)
## PROJECTION: Geographic, WGS84
## UNITS: Estimated persons per grid square
## MAPPING APPROACH: Random Forest
## FORMAT: Geotiff (zipped using 7-zip (open access tool): www.7-zip.org)
## FILENAMES: Example - NGA_ppp_v2b_2010_UNadj.tif = Nigeria (NGA) population per pixel (ppp), mapped using WorldPOP modelling version 2b (v2b) for 2010 (2010) adjusted to match UN national estimates (UNadj).
## DATE OF PRODUCTION: February 2017
##
## Also included: (i) Metadata html file, (ii) Google Earth file, (iii) Population datasets produced using original census year data (2006).
```

If you do persist, consider adding an answer with what you ended up doing or turning it into a package so others can use it as well.

Comment: thanks a ton for the effort above. I certainly owe you one. I am incredibly close to getting it. I have the tif file (which as you assumed correctly was what I was really after, used the txt as an example). I got the tif file downloaded and I can plot it, but run into "ERROR IN RGDAL, failure during Raster IO". I'm using Raster to extract the values of the tif files for specific shapefiles downloaded from GADM (a process I am very familiar with) Any idea why that would be the case? I've been battling it all day. In any case your post was incredibly helpful, thank you very much.

Comment: Just as a follow up, my raster extraction code works on directly downloaded TIF's from WorldPop, your code produces the same size file and looks exactly the same when I get the class details in R, and I can plot your file and looks great. But when I try to extract it, I get the IO error.

Comment: Sorry for all the posts, but I don't want to reply as an answer (until I have one!). I found this post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216151/why-do-i-get-error-failure-during-raster-io-when-extracting-values-from-my-ra) which obviously defeats the purpose of the web scraping, but is a good test. I loaded the downloaded file from your code into QGIS and saved as a tif. Worked like a charm when I loaded it in R. I have no idea what QGIS did to fix it, but if I can mimic whatever it did in R this would be done and I'd owe you more than one beer :)

Comment: Which file did you grab?

Comment: Started with Nigeria, then tested Rwanda and Bangladesh, all had the io error. I used getbin to write directly as a tif... I'm wondering of it doesn't have to do with a compression of some sort. The downloads from the non file list side come as zip files while the file list side comes directly as a tif

Comment: I was tried a variety of the year files from each. Thing is raster reads the downloads, its;s only when I try to do commands like raster extract (I tried velox as well) that the error happens. The download from your code plots fine after being read by raster.

Comment: gotcha. shld have time to poke at this later tonight.

Comment: FOLLOW UP: I THINK I HAVE IT. I'm running tests. Files were too big and were getting corrupted in memory. Using httr option write_disk

Comment: I have it, so don't bother spending more time on it @hrbrmstr. . . I'll post the full code when I finish it. Thanks again.

Comment: This is still the best answer I've ever gotten on stack. I refer to it all the time. Cheers again

Answer (score 1):

**HEY STACKOVERFLOW DELETERS, LOOK AT THIS. IT IS MEANT TO BE COMBINED WITH MY OTHER ANSWER BUT I'M LIMITED TO 30K CHARACTERS AND THERE IS A LOT OF CODE.**

This is now currently downloadable as a github package called spaceheater. Thanks again to @hrbrmstr without whom this wouldn't have been possible.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("nbarsch/spaceheater")
```

I split this into three functions:

```
getWPdatatypes("country") 
getWPoptions("country","datatype")  
getWPdownload("country","datatype",c ("options"),year)
###takes 0, 1 or 2 options. 0 is ""
```

__

```
getWPdatatypes("country") 
#Example
getWPdatatypes("Nigeria")
```

is the base level and returns a data frame of the available datatypes for that country from worldpop. Example datatypes are "Population", "Births", "UrbanChange".

_

```
getWPoptions("country", "datatype")
#Example
getWPoptions("Ghana", "Population")
```

is intended to be run after getWPdatatypes and returns a data frame of all of the options and years available for a country given a datatype.

```
getWPdownload("country", "datatype", c("options"), year)
#Example
getWPdownload("Benin", "Pregnancies", "pp", 2015)
```

Downloads the set thanks to hrbrmstr

If the set isn't year marked in the filename year is 9999. The world pop site has the year listed. Their file naming scheme is brutal, most of the code is due to inconsistent file names.

That being said I love their methodology and the gridded raster sets they build so if anybody uses the code please cite WorldPop. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is now part of spaceheater package on github, see other answer for instructions https://github.com/nbarsch/spaceheater. Code for reference on what I did is below.

Library:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(reshape2)
library(rangeBuilder)
library(stringr)
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)
```

Functions (due to char limits on SO I had to delete most of my #notes in code. See below answer for instructions. A ton of code is due to inconsistent filenames):

getWPdatatypes:

```
getWPdatatypes <- function (country)  {
country <- standardizeCountry(paste(country),fuzzyDist=30)
res <- GET(url="http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/data_sources/")
# Get the page contents
pg <- content(res)
summary_link_nodes <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href,'summary')]")
map(summary_link_nodes, html_nodes, xpath=".//../..") %>%
  map(html_children) %>%
  map(html_text) %>%
  map(~.[1:4]) %>%
  map(as.list) %>%
  map_df(set_names, c("continent", "country", "resolution", "data_type")) %>%
  bind_cols(
    data_frame(
      summary_link = sprintf("http://www.worldpop.org.uk%s", html_attr(summary_link_nodes, "href"))
    )
  ) -> world_pop_data
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Urban change", "UrbanChange", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Maternal and Newborn Health", "MaternalNewbornHealth", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Contraceptive Use", "ContraceptiveUse", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Age structures", "AgeStructures", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Dynamic Population", "DynamicPopulation", world_pop_data$data_type)
countryreference <- as.data.frame(world_pop_data)
countryreference <- countryreference[,c(1,2,4)]
countryreference <- countryreference[!(countryreference$country)=="N/A",]
world_pop_data <- world_pop_data[!(world_pop_data$country)=="N/A",]
countryreference$CountryStandard <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[,"country"], fuzzyDist=20)
countryreference$CountryEdit <- gsub("[()]", "", countryreference$country)
countryreference$CountryEdit2 <- gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(countryreference$country))
foreach(a=1:nrow(countryreference)) %do% {
  if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
    countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[a,"CountryEdit"], fuzzyDist=20)
    if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
      countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[a,"CountryEdit2"], fuzzyDist=20)
      if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
        countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- toupper(countryreference[a,"country"])
      }
    }
  }
}
exists <- isTRUE(paste(country) %in% as.character(countryreference$CountryStandard))
if(exists==FALSE){
  print("It appears this country is not in the WorldPop set, please check and try again")
  break
}
countryreference <- countryreference[,c(1,4,3)]
world_pop_data$CountryStandard <- countryreference[,2]
world_pop_data <- world_pop_data[,c(1,6,2,3,4,5)]
countryreference <- suppressMessages(dcast(countryreference, continent+CountryStandard ~ data_type))
countryreference <- filter(countryreference, countryreference$CountryStandard==country)
countryreference <- countryreference[,colSums(is.na(countryreference))<nrow(countryreference)]
print(countryreference[1,])
WPdata.types <<- countryreference[1,]
print("The above table has also been added to your working environment as dataframe: WPdata.types")
}
```

getWPoptions:

```
#Example
getWPdatatypes("Nigeria", "Population")

getWPoptions <- function (country, datatype)  {
  country <- standardizeCountry(paste(country),fuzzyDist=30)
  res <- GET(url="http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/data_sources/")
  # Get the page contents
  pg <- content(res)
  summary_link_nodes <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href,'summary')]")
  map(summary_link_nodes, html_nodes, xpath=".//../..") %>%
    map(html_children) %>%
    map(html_text) %>%
    map(~.[1:4]) %>%
    map(as.list) %>%
    map_df(set_names, c("continent", "country", "resolution", "data_type")) %>%
    bind_cols(
      data_frame(
        summary_link = sprintf("http://www.worldpop.org.uk%s", html_attr(summary_link_nodes, "href"))
      )
    ) -> world_pop_data
  world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Urban change", "UrbanChange", world_pop_data$data_type)
  world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Maternal and Newborn Health", "MaternalNewbornHealth", world_pop_data$data_type)
  world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Contraceptive Use", "ContraceptiveUse", world_pop_data$data_type)
  world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Age structures", "AgeStructures", world_pop_data$data_type)
  world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Dynamic Population", "DynamicPopulation", world_pop_data$data_type)
  countryreference <- as.data.frame(world_pop_data)
  countryreference <- countryreference[,c(1,2,4)]
  countryreference <- countryreference[!(countryreference$country)=="N/A",]
  world_pop_data <- world_pop_data[!(world_pop_data$country)=="N/A",]
  countryreference$CountryStandard <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[,"country"], fuzzyDist=20)
  countryreference$CountryEdit <- gsub("[()]", "", countryreference$country)
  countryreference$CountryEdit2 <- gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(countryreference$country))
  foreach(a=1:nrow(countryreference)) %do% {
    if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
      countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[a,"CountryEdit"], fuzzyDist=20)
      if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
        countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[a,"CountryEdit2"], fuzzyDist=20)
        if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
          countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- toupper(countryreference[a,"country"])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  exists <- isTRUE(paste(country) %in% as.character(countryreference$CountryStandard))
  if(exists==FALSE){
    print("It appears this country is not in the WorldPop set, please check and try again")
    break
  }
  countryreference <- countryreference[,c(1,4,3)]
  world_pop_data$CountryStandard <- countryreference[,2]
  world_pop_data <- world_pop_data[,c(1,6,2,3,4,5)]
  countryreference <- suppressMessages(dcast(countryreference, continent+CountryStandard ~ data_type))
  countryreference <- filter(countryreference, countryreference$CountryStandard==country)
  countryreference <- countryreference[,colSums(is.na(countryreference))<nrow(countryreference)]
  world_pop_data <- filter(world_pop_data, CountryStandard %in% countryreference$CountryStandard)
  world_pop_data <- filter(world_pop_data, data_type==paste(datatype))
  dataset_link <- as.character(world_pop_data[1,"summary_link"])
  GET(url=dataset_link) -> res2
  pg2 <- content(res2)
  fields <- html_nodes(pg2, "form#conform > input")
  fields <- set_names(xml_attr(fields, "value"), html_attr(fields, "name"))
  POST(
    url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/download/",
    add_headers(`Referer` = dataset_link),
    body = list(
      client_first_name = "",
      client_last_name = "",
      client_organization = "",
      client_country = "",
      client_email = "",
      client_message = "",
      zip_id = fields["zip_id"],
      zip_title = fields["zip_title"],
      decoy = fields["decoy"],
      website = "",
      download = "Browse Individual Files"
    ),
    encode = "form"
  ) -> res3
  pg3 <- content(res3)
  html_nodes(pg3, xpath=".//a[contains(., 'switch to')]") %>%
    html_attr("href") -> file_list_query_string
  GET(
    url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php",
    query = list(
      dataset = fields["zip_id"],
      action = "dir"
    )
  ) -> res4
  pg4 <- content(res4)
  data_frame(
    group_name = html_nodes(pg4, "a.dl") %>% html_text(),
    href = html_nodes(pg4, "a.dl") %>% html_attr("href")
  ) -> downloads
  downloads$istif <- str_sub(downloads$group_name,-4,-1)
  #Some such as senegal are inexplicably .TIF
  downloads$istif <- tolower(downloads$istif)
  downloads <- filter(downloads, istif==".tif")
  pg4charfile <- as.character(downloads[1,"group_name"])
  pg4charfile <- gsub(' {1,}','',pg4charfile)
  if(substr(pg4charfile,1,6)!="popmap"){
    if(grepl("\\d", pg4charfile)==TRUE){
      char4 <- substr(pg4charfile,4,4)
      char6 <-substr(pg4charfile,6,6)
      char9 <-substr(pg4charfile,9,9)
      char11 <-substr(pg4charfile,11,11)
      char4num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char4)))
      char6num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char6)))
      char9num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char9)))
      char11num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char11)))
      if(char4num==TRUE & char6num==TRUE){
        downloads$years <-substr(downloads$group_name,4,7)

      }
      if(char4num==TRUE & char6num==FALSE){
        downloads$years <-substr(downloads$group_name,4,5)
        getfouryear <- function (yearsvec)  {
          yrFlip = 50
          yearsvec <- as.numeric(yearsvec)
          yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] + 1900
          yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] + 2000
          return(yearsvec)
        }
        downloads$years <- getfouryear(downloads$years)
      }
      if(char9num==FALSE & char11num==TRUE){
        downloads$years <-substr(downloads$group_name,11,12)
        getfouryear <- function (yearsvec)  {
          yrFlip = 50
          yearsvec <- as.numeric(yearsvec)
          yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] + 1900
          yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] + 2000
          return(yearsvec)
        }
        downloads$years <- getfouryear(downloads$years)
      }
      if(char4num==FALSE & char6num==FALSE & char9num==TRUE){
        downloads$years <- str_extract(downloads$group_name, "\\d{4}")
      }
      if(char4num==FALSE & char6num==FALSE & char9num==FALSE & char11num==FALSE){
        downloads$years <- str_extract(downloads$group_name, "\\d{4}")
      }
    }else{downloads$years <- 9999}
  }else{
    downloads$years<- as.numeric(substr(downloads$group_name,7,8))
    getfouryear <- function (yearsvec)  {
      yrFlip = 50
      yearsvec <- as.numeric(yearsvec)
      yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] + 1900
      yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] + 2000
      return(yearsvec)
    }
    downloads$years <- getfouryear(downloads$years)
  }
  downloads <- downloads[!is.na(downloads$years),]
  ###Possible Options due to the inexplicable nature of their inconsistent file names
  possopt <- c("_pph_", "_ppp_", "_pp_", "uncert", "adj","_M.",  "_M_","_F.", "_F_", "interdecile", "povsd", "125", "200","wpipov", "ppipov", "incpov", "mpipov", "ANC", "SBA", "PNC")
  opttext <- c("Persons per hectare", "Persons per pixel", "per pixel", " uncertainty dataset showing 95% credible intervals",
               "adjusted to match UN estimates", "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "Uncertainty map", "poverty standard deviation map", "$1.25/day",
               "$2.00/day", "mean wealth index", "mean likelihood of living in poverty per grid square", "Income estimate USD per grid square", "%poverty by Multidimensional Poverty Index",
               "prob of four or more antenatal care visits at time of delivery", "prob of skilled birth attendance during delivery", "prob of postnatal care received within 48 hours of delivery")
  possoptdf <- data.frame(possopt, opttext, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  groupsubstr <- str_sub(downloads$group_name,4,-4)
  optionsforchoice<-foreach(a=1:nrow(downloads), .combine=rbind)%do%{
    theoptions<- foreach(b=1:length(opttext), .combine=cbind)%do%{
      matchoopt <- str_detect(downloads[a,"group_name"],coll(possopt[b]))
      if(matchoopt==TRUE){result <-possopt[b]}
      if(matchoopt==FALSE){result<- NA}
      if(b==13){
        mistake <- str_detect(downloads[a,"group_name"],"\\d{4}")
        if(mistake==TRUE){result <- NA}
      }
      result
    }
  }
  optionsforchoice<-do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(optionsforchoice),function(x) t(matrix(optionsforchoice[x,order(is.na(optionsforchoice[x,]))])) ))
  optionsforchoice <- as.data.frame(optionsforchoice, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  optionsforchoice <- optionsforchoice[,colSums(is.na(optionsforchoice))<nrow(optionsforchoice)]
  downloads <- cbind(downloads,optionsforchoice)
  optiters <- as.data.frame(optionsforchoice)
  if(length(optionsforchoice)==1){colnames(downloads)[5]<-"V1"}
  if(ncol(as.data.frame(optionsforchoice))==1){colnames(downloads)[5]<-"V1"}
  optiters <- ncol(optiters)
  ###join all the options so they can be displayed
  foreach(a=1:optiters)%do%{
    downloads <- merge(downloads, possoptdf, by.x=paste0("V",a), by.y="possopt", all.x=TRUE)
    coltochange <- ncol(downloads)
    colnames(downloads)[coltochange] <- paste0("possopt",a)
  }
  downloads$years <- as.numeric(downloads$years)
  downloads <- downloads[order(downloads$years),]
  ##Subsetting downloads to columns that only contain possopt
  downpossopt <- downloads[ ,  grepl( "possopt" , colnames( downloads ) ) ]
  downpossopt <- as.data.frame(downpossopt)
  downpossopt$code <- c(1:nrow(downpossopt))
  downloads$code <- c(1:nrow(downloads))
  rownames(downloads) <- c(1:nrow(downloads))
  rownames(downpossopt) <- c(1:nrow(downpossopt))
  if(ncol(downpossopt)==1){
    colnames(downpossopt) <- "possopt1"}
  downpossopt <- cbind(downloads$years, downpossopt)
  names(downpossopt)[names(downpossopt) == 'downloads$years'] <- 'years'
  names(downpossopt)[names(downpossopt) == 'V1'] <- 'years'
  possoptcodes <- c("pph", "ppp", "pp", "uncert", "adj","M",  "M","F", "F", "interdecile", "povsd", "125", "200","wpipov", "ppipov", "incpov", "mpipov", "ANC", "SBA", "PNC")
  possoptcodes <- as.data.frame(cbind(possoptcodes, opttext))
  possoptcodes <- possoptcodes[c(1:6,8,10:nrow(possoptcodes)),]
  names(downpossopt)[names(downpossopt) == 'downpossopt'] <- 'possopt1'
  foreach(a=1:optiters)%do%{
    downpossopt <- merge(downpossopt, possoptcodes, by.x=paste0("possopt",a), by.y="opttext", all.x=TRUE)
    coltochange <- ncol(downpossopt)
    colnames(downpossopt)[coltochange] <- paste0("OptionCode",a)
  }
  downpossopt <- as.data.frame(downpossopt)
  downpossopt <- downpossopt[order(downpossopt$code),]
  downpossopt <- downpossopt[,c(which(colnames(downpossopt)=="possopt1"),which(colnames(downpossopt)!="possopt1"))]
  downpossopt <- downpossopt[,c(which(colnames(downpossopt)=="years"),which(colnames(downpossopt)!="years"))]
  downpossopt$country <- countryreference[1,"CountryStandard"]
  downpossopt <- downpossopt[,c(which(colnames(downpossopt)=="country"),which(colnames(downpossopt)!="country"))]
  row.names(downpossopt) <- c(1:nrow(downpossopt))
  downpossoptcodes <- downpossopt[ ,  grepl( "OptionCode" , colnames( downpossopt ) ) ]
  downpossoptcodes <- as.data.frame(downpossoptcodes)
  print(downpossopt)
  WP.options <<- downpossopt
  print("The above table has also been added to your working environment as dataframe: WP.options")
}
```

getWPdownload:

```
#Example
getWPdownload("Benin", "Pregnancies", "pp", 2015)
#if the set is missing a year type 9999, 9999 will be returned for sets with missing years in getWPoptions. 

getWPdownload <- function (country, datatype, options, year)  {
country <- standardizeCountry(paste(country),fuzzyDist=30)
year <- as.numeric(year)
optionschosen <- paste(options, collapse = '-')
res <- GET(url="http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/data_sources/")
# Get the page contents
pg <- content(res)
summary_link_nodes <- html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//a[contains(@href,'summary')]")
map(summary_link_nodes, html_nodes, xpath=".//../..") %>%
  map(html_children) %>%
  map(html_text) %>%
  map(~.[1:4]) %>%
  map(as.list) %>%
  map_df(set_names, c("continent", "country", "resolution", "data_type")) %>%
  bind_cols(
    data_frame(
      summary_link = sprintf("http://www.worldpop.org.uk%s", html_attr(summary_link_nodes, "href"))
    )
  ) -> world_pop_data
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Urban change", "UrbanChange", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Maternal and Newborn Health", "MaternalNewbornHealth", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Contraceptive Use", "ContraceptiveUse", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Age structures", "AgeStructures", world_pop_data$data_type)
world_pop_data$data_type <- gsub("Dynamic Population", "DynamicPopulation", world_pop_data$data_type)
countryreference <- as.data.frame(world_pop_data)
countryreference <- countryreference[,c(1,2,4)]
countryreference <- countryreference[!(countryreference$country)=="N/A",]
world_pop_data <- world_pop_data[!(world_pop_data$country)=="N/A",]
###Filter country names so they match the desired country
countryreference$CountryStandard <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[,"country"], fuzzyDist=20)
countryreference$CountryEdit <- gsub("[()]", "", countryreference$country)
countryreference$CountryEdit2 <- gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",as.character(countryreference$country))
foreach(a=1:nrow(countryreference)) %do% {
  if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
    countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[a,"CountryEdit"], fuzzyDist=20)
    if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
      countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- standardizeCountry(countryreference[a,"CountryEdit2"], fuzzyDist=20)
      if(countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"]==""){
        countryreference[a,"CountryStandard"] <- toupper(countryreference[a,"country"])
      }
    }
  }
}
exists <- isTRUE(paste(country) %in% as.character(countryreference$CountryStandard))
if(exists==FALSE){
  print("It appears this country is not in the WorldPop set, please check and try again")
  break
}
countryreference <- countryreference[,c(1,4,3)]
world_pop_data$CountryStandard <- countryreference[,2]
world_pop_data <- world_pop_data[,c(1,6,2,3,4,5)]
countryreference <- suppressMessages(dcast(countryreference, continent+CountryStandard ~ data_type))
countryreference <- filter(countryreference, countryreference$CountryStandard==country)
countryreference <- countryreference[,colSums(is.na(countryreference))<nrow(countryreference)]
world_pop_data <- filter(world_pop_data, CountryStandard %in% countryreference$CountryStandard)
world_pop_data <- filter(world_pop_data, data_type==paste(datatype))
dataset_link <- as.character(world_pop_data[1,"summary_link"])
GET(url=dataset_link) -> res2
pg2 <- content(res2)
fields <- html_nodes(pg2, "form#conform > input")
fields <- set_names(xml_attr(fields, "value"), html_attr(fields, "name"))
POST(
  url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/download/",
  add_headers(`Referer` = dataset_link),
  body = list(
    client_first_name = "",
    client_last_name = "",
    client_organization = "",
    client_country = "",
    client_email = "",
    client_message = "",
    zip_id = fields["zip_id"],
    zip_title = fields["zip_title"],
    decoy = fields["decoy"],
    website = "",
    download = "Browse Individual Files"
  ),
  encode = "form"
) -> res3
pg3 <- content(res3)
html_nodes(pg3, xpath=".//a[contains(., 'switch to')]") %>%
  html_attr("href") -> file_list_query_string
GET(
  url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php",
  query = list(
    dataset = fields["zip_id"],
    action = "dir"
  )
) -> res4
pg4 <- content(res4)
data_frame(
  group_name = html_nodes(pg4, "a.dl") %>% html_text(),
  href = html_nodes(pg4, "a.dl") %>% html_attr("href")
) -> downloads
downloads$istif <- str_sub(downloads$group_name,-4,-1)
#Some such as senegal are inexplicably .TIF
downloads$istif <- tolower(downloads$istif)
downloads <- filter(downloads, istif==".tif")
pg4charfile <- as.character(downloads[1,"group_name"])
pg4charfile <- gsub(' {1,}','',pg4charfile)
if(substr(pg4charfile,1,6)!="popmap"){
if(grepl("\\d", pg4charfile)==TRUE){
  char4 <- substr(pg4charfile,4,4)
  char6 <-substr(pg4charfile,6,6)
  char9 <-substr(pg4charfile,9,9)
  char11 <-substr(pg4charfile,11,11)
  char4num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char4)))
  char6num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char6)))
  char9num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char9)))
  char11num <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(char11)))
  if(char4num==TRUE & char6num==TRUE){
    downloads$years <-substr(downloads$group_name,4,7)
  }
  if(char4num==TRUE & char6num==FALSE){
    downloads$years <-substr(downloads$group_name,4,5)
    getfouryear <- function (yearsvec)  {
      yrFlip = 50
      yearsvec <- as.numeric(yearsvec)
      yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] + 1900
      yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] + 2000
      return(yearsvec)
    }
    downloads$years <- getfouryear(downloads$years)
  }
  if(char9num==FALSE & char11num==TRUE){
    downloads$years <-substr(downloads$group_name,11,12)
    getfouryear <- function (yearsvec)  {
      yrFlip = 50
      yearsvec <- as.numeric(yearsvec)
      yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] + 1900
      yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] + 2000
      return(yearsvec)
    }
    downloads$years <- getfouryear(downloads$years)
  }
  if(char4num==FALSE & char6num==FALSE & char9num==TRUE){
    downloads$years <- str_extract(downloads$group_name, "\\d{4}")
  }
  if(char4num==FALSE & char6num==FALSE & char9num==FALSE & char11num==FALSE){
    downloads$years <- str_extract(downloads$group_name, "\\d{4}")
  }
}else{downloads$years <- 9999}
}else{
  downloads$years<- as.numeric(substr(downloads$group_name,7,8))
  getfouryear <- function (yearsvec)  {
    yrFlip = 50
    yearsvec <- as.numeric(yearsvec)
    yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec > yrFlip] + 1900
    yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] <- yearsvec[yearsvec < yrFlip] + 2000
    return(yearsvec)
  }
  downloads$years <- getfouryear(downloads$years)
  }
downloads <- downloads[!is.na(downloads$years),]
possopt <- c("_pph_", "_ppp_", "_pp_", "uncert", "adj","_M.",  "_M_","_F.", "_F_", "interdecile", "povsd", "125", "200","wpipov", "ppipov", "incpov", "mpipov", "ANC", "SBA", "PNC")
opttext <- c("Persons per hectare", "Persons per pixel", "per pixel", " uncertainty dataset showing 95% credible intervals",
              "adjusted to match UN estimates", "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "Uncertainty map", "poverty standard deviation map", "$1.25/day",
              "$2.00/day", "mean wealth index", "mean likelihood of living in poverty per grid square", "Income estimate USD per grid square", "%poverty by Multidimensional Poverty Index",
              "prob of four or more antenatal care visits at time of delivery", "prob of skilled birth attendance during delivery", "prob of postnatal care received within 48 hours of delivery")
possoptdf <- data.frame(possopt, opttext, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
groupsubstr <- str_sub(downloads$group_name,4,-4)
###get options for each file from the worldpop selected country and datatype###
optionsforchoice<-foreach(a=1:nrow(downloads), .combine=rbind)%do%{
  theoptions<- foreach(b=1:length(opttext), .combine=cbind)%do%{
    matchoopt <- str_detect(downloads[a,"group_name"],coll(possopt[b]))
    if(matchoopt==TRUE){result <-possopt[b]}
    if(matchoopt==FALSE){result<- NA}
    if(b==13){
      mistake <- str_detect(downloads[a,"group_name"],"\\d{4}")
      if(mistake==TRUE){result <- NA}
    }
    result
  }
}
optionsforchoice<-do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(optionsforchoice),function(x) t(matrix(optionsforchoice[x,order(is.na(optionsforchoice[x,]))])) ))
optionsforchoice <- as.data.frame(optionsforchoice, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
optionsforchoice <- optionsforchoice[,colSums(is.na(optionsforchoice))<nrow(optionsforchoice)]
downloads <- cbind(downloads,optionsforchoice)
optiters <- as.data.frame(optionsforchoice)
if(length(optionsforchoice)==1){colnames(downloads)[5]<-"V1"}
if(ncol(as.data.frame(optionsforchoice))==1){colnames(downloads)[5]<-"V1"}
optiters <- ncol(optiters)
foreach(a=1:optiters)%do%{
  downloads <- merge(downloads, possoptdf, by.x=paste0("V",a), by.y="possopt", all.x=TRUE)
  coltochange <- ncol(downloads)
  colnames(downloads)[coltochange] <- paste0("possopt",a)
}
downloads$years <- as.numeric(downloads$years)
downloads <- downloads[order(downloads$years),]
##Subsetting downloads to columns that only contain possopt
downpossopt <- downloads[ ,  grepl( "possopt" , colnames( downloads ) ) ]
downpossopt <- as.data.frame(downpossopt)
downpossopt$code <- c(1:nrow(downpossopt))
downloads$code <- c(1:nrow(downloads))
rownames(downloads) <- c(1:nrow(downloads))
rownames(downpossopt) <- c(1:nrow(downpossopt))
if(ncol(downpossopt)==1){
  colnames(downpossopt) <- "possopt1"}
downpossopt <- cbind(downloads$years, downpossopt)
names(downpossopt)[names(downpossopt) == 'downloads$years'] <- 'years'
names(downpossopt)[names(downpossopt) == 'V1'] <- 'years'
###get the right codes for the function
possoptcodes <- c("pph", "ppp", "pp", "uncert", "adj","M",  "M","F", "F", "interdecile", "povsd", "125", "200","wpipov", "ppipov", "incpov", "mpipov", "ANC", "SBA", "PNC")
possoptcodes <- as.data.frame(cbind(possoptcodes, opttext))
possoptcodes <- possoptcodes[c(1:6,8,10:nrow(possoptcodes)),]
names(downpossopt)[names(downpossopt) == 'downpossopt'] <- 'possopt1'
foreach(a=1:optiters)%do%{
  downpossopt <- merge(downpossopt, possoptcodes, by.x=paste0("possopt",a), by.y="opttext", all.x=TRUE)
  coltochange <- ncol(downpossopt)
  colnames(downpossopt)[coltochange] <- paste0("OptionCode",a)
}
downpossopt <- as.data.frame(downpossopt)
downpossopt <- downpossopt[order(downpossopt$code),]
downpossopt <- downpossopt[,c(which(colnames(downpossopt)=="possopt1"),which(colnames(downpossopt)!="possopt1"))]
downpossopt <- downpossopt[,c(which(colnames(downpossopt)=="years"),which(colnames(downpossopt)!="years"))]
downpossopt$country <- countryreference[1,"CountryStandard"]
downpossopt <- downpossopt[,c(which(colnames(downpossopt)=="country"),which(colnames(downpossopt)!="country"))]
row.names(downpossopt) <- c(1:nrow(downpossopt))
downpossoptcodes <- downpossopt[ ,  grepl( "OptionCode" , colnames( downpossopt ) ) ]
downpossoptcodes <- as.data.frame(downpossoptcodes)
if(ncol(downpossoptcodes)>1){
downpossoptcodes <- data.frame(x=apply(downpossoptcodes,1,function(x) {paste(x[!is.na(x)],collapse='-')}))
}
colnames(downpossoptcodes) <- "optionspossible"
downloads <- as.data.frame(cbind(downloads, downpossoptcodes))
downloads <- filter(downloads, downloads$years==year)
if(optionschosen!=""){
downloads2 <- filter(downloads, downloads$optionspossible==optionschosen)
if(is.na(downloads2[1,1]) & length(options)>1){
  optionschosen <- paste0(options[2],"-", options[1], collapse='')
  downloads2 <- filter(downloads, downloads$optionspossible==optionschosen)
}
}else{downloads2 <- filter(downloads, is.na(downloads$optionspossible))}
readme_query_stringdownload <- as.character(downloads2[1,"href"])
filenamedest <- as.character(paste0(country,downloads2[1,"group_name"]))
GET(
  url = "http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/files/index.php",
  query = parse_url(readme_query_stringdownload)$query,
  progress(),
  verbose(),
  write_disk(paste0(filenamedest), overwrite=TRUE)
)-> res5
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18732629)

Comment: See below man. I hit character limits. This is exactly the answer to my original question. I'm putting it in a package and I'll reference that in an edit of my below answer, but c'mon stop deleting this or make it so I can go over 30k characters so I can have my functions and instructions on one answer.